# smtp.live.com - mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.3 requested action aborted; user not authenticated

Tags: c#, email

I have read other answers on the stackoverflow. but none of the solutions work for me.

I'm trying to send email through live.com, but unable to it.

The error message:

```
mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.3 requested action aborted;
user not authenticated
```

The code:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("email@live.com");
mail.To.Add("someone@someone.com");
mail.Subject = "hello";
mail.Body = "awefkljj kawefl";
mail.IsBodyHtml = false;

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587);
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@live.com", "password");
smtp.Send(mail);
```

Are you able to send the email by using above code?

It works before, last year, but it is no more working now.

What had been changed?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I ran into an issue where I was unable to send emails using the smtp.live.com SMTP server from certain hosts -- particulary Azure hosts. In my case, the SMTP attempt was from a host that I had never used to sign-in previously, so the attempt was blocked with the 5.7.3 error:

> Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.3 requested action aborted; user not authenticated

The solution was to browse to the account settings, locate the SMTP request in its recent activity, and select "This was me":

[image: Verify the SMTP attempt]

Comment: I really cant find that settings... :/

Comment: This is a bit harder to find now: https://account.microsoft.com/ -> Security -> Review Recent activity

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using a gmail account but was telling the service otherwise.
I changed:

```
smtp.Host = "smtp.live.com";
```

To:

```
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
```

Which resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

This Solved My Problem:

```
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myaccount@live.com","mypassword");
```

`UseDefaultCredentials`property should set to false before setting Credentials

Answer (score 1):

If you have this problem on 2017, and you think you are probaly using an office 365 account, make sure to change the host to "smtp.office365.com". It worked for me.